# How do I connect to a pc through another pc using ssh

Tags: ssh

I have **three** Computers.

**PC1** and **PC2** is on a private LAN, where **PC1** is known to **PC2** as `192.168.0.2`

**PC2** and **PC3** is on a another  LAN, where **PC2** is known to **PC3** as `192.168.123.101`

How can I connect to **PC1** from **PC3** with SSH.

Is there something like:

```
ssh user@192.168.0.2 -via user@192.168.123.101
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@192.168.123.101'
```

Then you can simply run `ssh PC1`.

Best used through an alias in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host PC1
HostName 192.168.0.2
User user
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@192.168.123.101
```

For older versions of OpenSSH that don't have the `-W` option (I think this means ≤5.4), make sure that [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is available on PC2 and use

```
Host PC1
HostName 192.168.0.2
User user
ProxyCommand ssh user@192.168.123.101 nc %h %p
```

Comment: +1 Yep, and I have a similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010808/1122282#1122282 with some more details.

Comment: needed to install netcat

Answer (score 4):

Using SSH there is a clear solution:

1. on your local machine set up your `~/.ssh/config` such that it has the following:

   ```
   host WhatYouWillCallTheConnection
       hostname the.gateway.server.address.com
       user YourUsernameOnTheGateway
   ```
2. On both the gateway and the end server you'd like to connect to, make sure that you have your local client's public keys located in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. On the gateway machine you need to alter the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` such that at the beginning of the line that specifies your client's public key, add the forced command as follows:

   ```
   command="ssh -A user_name@ServerTheGatewaySees.ButTheClientCant.net" ...yourPublicKey....
   ```

The `-A` is to forward the agent if you don't like to send passwords all the time...

This way, anytime you do something like `ssh WhatYouWillCallTheConnection` it will run straight through the gateway and connect you to the server on the other side transparently.

Comment: Don't use `ssh -A` if you don't trust the administrator of the gateway machine.  He can't get your private key, but as long as you're connected to the gateway with `ssh -A`, he can use the forwarded agent to connect to other machines as you.

Answer (score 2):

Port Forwarding might come in handy.
From PC1:

```
~# ssh -fN -L 22:PC3:7777 -l <user> PC2
```

7777 can be just any port (provided it is not already being used). I just like that number, plus any "ordering up" I can manage by +1 's (7778, 7779, etc, etc).

This being done, you will have a 'transparent' tunnel from PC1's local port 7777 to PC3's port 22. Just issue:

```
~# ssh -l <user> -p 7777 localhost
```

And you should be on PC3.
You can also use -D to dynamically forward a port if you want a SOCKS proxy established.

```
~# ssh -D <someport> -fN -L 22:PC3:7777 -l <user> PC2
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The 2017+(since [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh)v7.3)-answer to this is [ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump):

`ssh -J user@jumphost user@destination`

, which is short for:

`ssh -o "ProxyJump user@jumphost" user@destination`

This can be shortened to **`ssh dest`** with a `~/.ssh/config` snippet as such:

```
Host jump
    User MyJumpHostUser
    Hostname Jump.host.tld

Host dest
    ProxyJump jump
    User MyDestUser
    Hostname des.tin.ati.on
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know for this is ssh scripting with [Belier](http://www.ohmytux.com/belier/):

> Belier allows opening a shell or
>   executing a command on a remote
>   computer through a SSH connection. The
>   main feature of Belier is its ability
>   to cross several intermediate
>   computers before realizing the job.

A while ago I found this [README.sshhop](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/communications/ist/corpora/README.sshhop) on the MIT Lincoln Laboratory Homepage, but I wasn't able to find any further information about that. Does somebody know more?