# How to use rsync with a remote remote host

Tags: rsync, synchronization, ssh-tunneling

I am a happy user of `rsync -e ssh` and use it to synchronize data between my machine and a remote host using

```
rsync -avz -e ssh me@hostA:~/folder ~/folder
```

And this did what I needed until now.

I am now working with a configuration where the access is a bit more complicated. Suppose now `~/folder` is on `hostB`, but `hostB` is not directly accessible from my machine, but only indirectly via `hostA`.

So if I only want to see the folder on `hostB`. I first need to ssh to `hostA`, then to `hostB` after which I can see my files in `~/folder` on the remote host.

My question now is, what is the (best) method to use `rsync` directly between my machine and `hostB`?

Unfortunately this is the configuration I need to work with. Assume there is no possibility to temporarily store the data on `hostA` itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [How do I connect to a pc through another pc using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/how-do-i-connect-to-a-pc-through-another-pc-using-ssh)

You create a new `~/.ssh/config` entry with the name tunnelb:

```
Host tunnelb
HostName hostB
User user
ProxyCommand ssh user@hostA nc %h %p
```

If you have a recent version of ssh you can use `Proxycommand ssh user@hostA -W %h:%p` instead. This is preferred as it does not rely on `nc`

Now you can just use `rsync -e ssh tunnelb:~/folder ~/folder` as it will use the defined entry in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Variant 1:

First, start ssh on hostA permanently with local port forwarding in another terminal. E.g.:

```
ssh -N -v -L 22022:hostB:22 hostA
```

Then, "feed" rsync with ssh to `localhost:22022`. One variant is to write to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host hostB
HostName localhost
Port 22022
```

#### Variant 2:

Replace `-e ssh` with `-e` to some script which contains:

```
ssh hostA 'ssh hostB' "$@"
```

I didn't try it so some details would be elaborated additionally.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Was not able to successfully rsync yet. For the portforwarding I get an errormessage like `debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found`. For the second variant I get `bash: hostA: command not found`. I will puzzle a bit on you suggestion, any more hints more than welcome