# Ssh through two servers and a user in one command line

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a pc through another pc using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/how-do-i-connect-to-a-pc-through-another-pc-using-ssh)

How to go about doing in one command line the following operations?

```
$ ssh server-one
$ su - user
$ ssh server-two
```

Of course I cannot directly `ssh user@server-two`

Comment: This may be a starting point http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43097/14084

Answer (score 6):

```
ssh server-one -t ssh user@localhost -t ssh server-two
```

From `man ssh`:

```
     -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be 
             used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs 
             on a remote machine, which can be very useful, 
             e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
             options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -t server-one 'su - user -c "ssh server-two"'
```