# Changing user while scp

Tags: users, scp

I need to copy file between Linux machines. The problem that the user I use to login (`myuser`), is different from the user that can access the file.

If I just `ssh` to the machine, I can switch the user using `sudo su someuser`, can I do it somehow while `scp`?

While using WinSCP I managed to do it, by configuring the SCP/Shell, so I believe there must be a similar way to do it via pure shell.

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you login as the user who manipulates the file?

Comment: Because it's impossible to login using the other user.

Comment: How about connecting with `ssh` and executing `scp`, something like this: `ssh myuser@host "sudo scp ..."` ?

Comment: Maybe the answer here can work in such a situation? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43094/how-to-use-rsync-with-a-remote-remote-host @Tarlog This assumes that on the remote machine itself, you can ssh someuser@remote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that the user you CAN ssh to doesn't need a password to sudo su into the target user, you can try this:

```
dd if=myfile | ssh some.host "sudo -u targetuser dd of=myfile"
```

... Mind, I'm still unconvinced that simply configuring `targetuser` to only allow scp/sftp/rsync over SSH and using a RSA keypair for authentication isn't a much better option.

Comment: or `tar -cvf - * | ssh user@host "sudo -u targetuser tar -C /targetdir -xf -"` for a bunch of files

Comment: Also true, and I suppose we can debate whether `-z` or `-j` are useful depending on connection speed and computer hardware on either side...

Answer (score 4):

If you know the credentials to the other user (`someuser`) you can just specify it on your `scp` call.

From the `man scp` page:

> File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that
>   the
>        file is to be copied to/from that host.  Local file names can be made
>        explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file
>        names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.  Copies between two remote hosts
>        are also permitted.

Here's the syntax used:

```
[[user@]host:]/path/to/file
```

**Example**

You want to copy the file `/home/foo/bar` from `host1` to your localhost, using user `someuser`, here's the command:

```
scp someuser@host1:/home/foo/bar .
```

You will be asked for authentication (password, keys, ...).

Comment: It's impossible to login as the other user.

Comment: Then establish an scp/rsync-only login with RSA keys.

Comment: It's impossible to use the other user using any kind of login. Other then that I already use RSA keys for ssh/scp.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably **possible**, but I'd say it's a very awkward way to go about it.

My first suggestion is to login as that user. Even if you don't have that user's password, you can add your own public ssh key to their authorized_keys and then scp using their key, as rahmu shows.

If that's not possible, my second suggestion is to login by ssh, sudo to the user and create a tarfile of the files you want to copy and put it somewhere that your own user can read. Then scp down that tarfile.

Comment: It's impossible to login the the other user. Yep, I figured out the second suggestion myself. Looking for an easy way :)

Comment: The link posted by gcb should be of service, then. At least if you're going to be doing this more than once. Or, of course, you could change the access rights to the file to give your own user access to it.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create a script (which is going to be used multiple times of course) that will be used by different users. So granting the access to me won't really help. Anyone who is able to 'sudo su otheruser' should be able to run the script.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd start with the link from gcb, then if you have problems with the script post it and see if we can crowdsource some help.

Answer (score 1):

use `-S` on the `scp` command

e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/87597/how-to-perform-scp-as-a-sudo-user

it will allow you to execute a script, on much like i believe you were doing with the winscp use case.