# How can I mount a remote sshfs directory of an publicly inaccessible server on my inaccessible client machine?

Tags: ssh, mount, ssh-tunneling, sshfs, tunneling

This is an extension of [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/139023/how-to-mount-remote-sshfs-via-intermediate-machine-tunneling) by @Andrei

> How to mount remote SSHFS via intermediate machine? Tunneling?

I'm in the same situation that I want to mount a remote directory, however the difference is that both machines `A` and `B` are not publicly exposed on the internet. `A` is my local work station.

**So I can neither ssh from `A -> B`, nor `B -> A`.**

What I regularly do, is establish a reverse connection from `B -> C`, where `C` is a rented virtual server (VPS). A script doing this connection (and reconnecting in case of lost connection) is started via the `@reboot` key of `cron`.

```
user@pcB $ ssh -R 2048:localhost:22 -p<port> user@serverC
```

Then, to go from `A -> B` I take the intermediate route `A -> C -> B`.

```
user@pcA $ ssh serverC
user@serverC $ ssh -p 2048 user@localhost
user@pcB $ # okay, logged in.
```

I'm looking for a way to mount the directory `pcB:/home/user` on `pcA`.

[How do I connect to a pc through another pc using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/how-do-i-connect-to-a-pc-through-another-pc-using-ssh) is similar, but the solutions provided don't work in this scenario: the connection map in my case is `A -> C <- B` not `A -> C -> B`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was easier than I thought!

All one has to do is bind the port `2048` of `serverC` to a port on `pcA`. For simplicity I use the same port number `2048`:

```
user@pcA $ ssh -L 2048:localhost:2048 user@serverC
```

One needs to keep this terminal window open.

Then, mounting the directory `pcB:/home/user` locally on `pcA` looks like this:

```
sshfs -o port=2048 user@localhost:/home/user/ /mnt/pcB
```

*Nice side-effect:* This means you can also use efficient X-server connections, e.g. `freeNX` or `vnc` to retrieve a display of `pcB`. Just connect to `localhost:2048` and use the correct credentials (user name/password) for machine `pcB`!

If you don't want to have to keep a terminal open for the connection, you use:

```
ssh -NfL 2048:localhost:2048 user@serverC
```

*Note that doing this might violate your employers'/organizational security policy, so make sure to get appropriate permissions.*