# How can I use a reverse tunnel with sshfs?

Tags: mount, ssh-tunneling, sshfs

I have a `local` machine which connects via ssh to a `remote` machine using a `middle` machine and a reverse ssh tunnel from `remote` to `middle`:

```
remote$ ssh -p <sshd port> -NTR <local port>:localhost:<sshd port> middle
```

Thus both

```
local$ ssh -J middle:<sshd port> localhost -p <local port>
```

and

```
local$ sftp -J middle:<sshd port> -P <local port> localhost
```

connect to `remote`.

What is the syntax for sshfs to use this existing reverse tunnel to mount `remote:~` onto `local:~/mnt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How can I mount a remote sshfs directory of an publicly inaccessible server on my inaccessible client machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76935/how-can-i-mount-a-remote-sshfs-directory-of-an-publicly-inaccessible-server-on-m) provides one way of doing this. Are there others which don't require setting up a forward tunnel from `local` to `middle`?