# SCP command with selected file and directories for download asks for password for each new file or directory

Tags: password, scp, file-transfer

On my Fedora 20 system I use scp a lot, and this is the second time I encounter this. When I run this command:

```
scp -r -P PORT user@host:/home/user/something/{file1,folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4} folder/folder2/
```

it asks me for the password for each file/directory it transfers.

```
user@host's password: "password here"
```

Question:

What is happening here?

Is this normal, I would think this is very peculiar behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your local shell (probably bash) is expanding

```
user@host:/home/user/something/{file1,folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4}
```

into:

```
user@host:/home/user/something/file1 user@host:/home/user/something/folder1 user@host:/home/user/something/folder2 user@host:/home/user/something/folder3 user@host:/home/user/something/folder4
```

Instead, you can do:

```
scp -r -P PORT user@host:"/home/user/something/file1 /home/user/something/folder1 /home/user/something/folder2 /home/user/something/folder3 /home/user/something/folder4" folder/folder2/
```

or, if you know user's login shell on the remote end is bash, you can use brace expansion too:

```
scp -r -P PORT user@host:"/home/user/something/{file1,folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4}" folder/folder2/
```

to have the remote shell split the string into arguments instead of the local shell.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's normal. What happens is that your shell expands the braces before running the command so what you're actually running is

```
scp -r -P PORT user@host:/home/user/something/file1 \ 
               user@host:/home/user/something/folder1 \ 
               user@host:/home/user/something/folder3 \ 
               user@host:/home/user/something/folder4 folder/folder2
```

Basically, `scp` sees multiple connection requests so opens a new connection for each of them. One way <del>The simplest way</del>(using quotes as suggested by @geirha is simpler for a one-off operation) to solve this is to set up passwordless `ssh`/`scp`:

```
$ ssh-keygen 
$ ssh-copy-id -p PORT user@host
```

After running those two commands once (and answering the prompts as needed), you will be able to `ssh`/`scp` without using a password for all future ssh connections. This is i) [actually more secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9870) and ii) *much* more convenient.

Comment: +1, nice way (of course the ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id has to be made only once). I'd say that it is more secure ... *only* if you make *sure* the private part is "unreachable" by anyone except that user... Which is not always easy.

Comment: @OlivierDulac what do you mean? The `id.rsa` will have `600` permissions by default and `ssh` won't even work if it doesn't. This means it is safe from anyone but `root` and nothing is really safe from `root`, certainly not passwords.

Comment: I just meant to add this comment, so that people setting up a passwordless access take into account (and grok) the fact that the private key has to be in a safe environment and unreadable/unshared/etc. (ie, it's a gentle way to point this out, as the ones asking may not know all the implications that sharing/letting the private key be accessed could have)

Comment: @OlivierDulac ah, fair enough. I didn't think it worth mentioning because 1) it happens automatically when using `ssh-keygen` and 2) ssh/scp will complain and ask for a password if the file is readable by anyone else. At least on Linux anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`scp` isn't very smart: when given multiple command line arguments that are files from the same remote host, it opens a new connection for each argument.

You can use `rsync` instead of `scp`, it's smarter this way (and in other ways).

```
rsync -r -e 'ssh -P PORT' user@host:/home/user/something/{file1,folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4} folder/folder2/
```

Another approach is to [pass a single argument to `scp` that describes multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167119).

A different approach is to set up your system so that you don't have to authenticate all the time. Preferably, [set up key authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work), which is in most scenarios both more convenient and more secure. Alternatively, or in addition, [set up connection sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167089/copying-a-file-using-ssh-over-a-tunnel-with-cert-forwarding/167240#167240), so that you only need to authenticate once per session. In any case, set up an alias so you don't have to specify the username and port every time. In your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r

Host nick
HostName real-host-name.example.com
User bob
Port 1234
```

Run `ssh -Nf nick` to open a connection, and then all subsequent connections to `nick` will piggyback on the existing connection. Now you can just run

```
scp -r nick:/home/user/something/{file1,folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4} folder/folder2/
```